# Does an advanced calculator like GeoGebra exist for the terminal?

Tags: software-recommendation

I want to be able to do advanced math calculations and equation solving **from the command line**. I want to be able to derive, integrate, do trigonometric operations and solve equations (linear, quadratic, cubic, differential, parametric, integral ++). Drawing graphs would have been nice as well, but not necessary. What I want is something like CAS in GeoGebra.

Does any software like this exist?

Comment: Yes, [Geogebra (with CAS) for Linux](http://www.geogebra.net/installers/deb.php?arch=amd64)

Comment: @M.Becerra But I want to be able to use it in the terminal, I don't believe GeoGebra offers this

Comment: Maybe this http://www.gnuplot.info/

Comment: You can try **octave**. (The syntax is similar to matlab.) You force it to run in command-line mode by the command line `octave --no-gui`

Answer (score 1):

GeoGebra uses the computer algebra system [Giac](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Eparisse/giac.html) in its CAS window. Giac is available as a [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/xcas) in Ubuntu. When you install it, there is a graphical user interface available via the `xcas` command, but a simple terminal based interface can also be started via the command `giac`.